# sudo service command not found when installing mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, macos, service, path

I am currently on OS/X using macbook. I want to stop the instance of mongodb service running. Hence I tried:

```
> sudo service mongodb stop
sudo: service: command not found
```

After looking up on Google, they asked me to add PATH hence I did the following:

```
> `vim ~/.bash_profile` (created a new bash_profile) and added the following there:

   export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH
```

It does not seem to work and I still get the same error:

Comment: How did you install mongodb?

Comment: I think the community in general and you too would benefit, should you spend some time reading about [what topics are welcome here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please consider closing your question and asking it instead in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The command you are using is for Linux. To kill all mongod instances on your system, you have to issue

```
killall mongod
```

in a Terminal window. In order to kill a specific mongod instance, you have to issue

```
ps ax | grep [m]ongod
```

This will give you a list of mongod instances currently running on your Mac. Pick the one you want to stop (you can distinguish them via their command line options) and have a look to the very left of that line. The number is the process id (or pid for short) of that mongod instance. You kill that instance by issuing

```
kill <pid>
```

Replacing `<pid>` with the actual process id.